# GAE channel api with django-nonrel

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, channel-api

Can anyone please let me know, does Google app engine channel api be integrated within django-nonrel ? My whole application is in django-nonrel running on GAE but now I need to use the channel api for server push purpose. 
I think channel api uses GAE webapp. Will it work with django-nonrel ?

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: None of the APIs care what framework you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No-matter which framework you are using, you can always use the provided appengine api's as they are documented. There is no "django specific abstraction" for the channel api last I checked, but it will work happily alongside anything else you create.